# Storing Downloadable Content Securely

Tags: web-hosting, security, server, video

For a site where users can purchase videos for download.

What would be the best way to store the media? Any other helpful considerations are more than welcome.

- Outside the root directory?
- Seperate server?
- Changing permissions?

Also, to improve preformance, is there such a thing as hosting your website on one server. Then on another server configured more for large downloads and bandwidth, hosting all the downloadable content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer isn't that easy.

First things first ask yourself how many videos are you thinking about to store, and how many users and downloads are going to happen.

For scalability purposes, you should consider using a CDN (Content Distribtion Network). This fits and go further for your question about performance.

Also this go for your first question, once the content will be in many servers, it doesn't and shouldn't be in your domain. Let the domain control access/security, the CDN control the download.

But, again this is a scalable, high-traffic solution. For a small user base, simple videos, you can cut off a lot of implementation work and distriution issues by simpling using youtube/flickr/google videos.

Set them as private, then use their API to show content under your domain after logon.